# Is there an option to ping someone with discord bot using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to ping a role but it's like "ghost ping", because it mentions the role, but I don't receive any ping from that channel, it's just a message with this role.

Here you have the code

```
@client.tree.command(name="duty", description="ping @SASP wbijajcie na służbę (only adm)")
    @discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def nagana(interaction: discord.Interaction,):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"<@&1064986634963140628>, Zapraszam na służbę")
```

I tried many options and none of that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can set mention permissions using the `allowed_mentions` option in the function call.

```py
async def nagana(interaction: discord.Interaction,):
    await interaction.response.send_message(
        f"<@&1064986634963140628>, Zapraszam na służbę", 
        allowed_mentions=discord.AllowedMentions(roles=True),
    )
```